# Django Saving Dates

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-2.7, django-views

Currently I have a script that queries TS3 servers and then stores their SID and amount of players in a database table that can be used by Django to render charts. Everything works, including the rendering of the charts however I am unable to remove the seconds from a date when saving. I have a variable called "startTime" to get the date and time. This works and gives an output like this "04-04-2013 16:58" however when saving it to the database, I get something like this "04-04-2013 16:58:32". This is what I am using to get the date and time.

```
startTime = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
```

Any ideas on how to remove the seconds before saving or even after by updating the rows in the database? I am using a Charfield to store the date.

Comment: why are you using charfield? you could use DateField, and your issue would be resolved. You can have CharField in the model, and the form widget as a DateField. That should resolve your issue too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use the datetime.replace method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) like this: `datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)`